# Why is there no output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am supposed to create a program in which I am supposed to add numbers if they are string and concatenate numbers if they are integer.
This is my code:

```
num1 = input("Enter an integer or string: ")
num2 = input("Enter an integer or string: ")
  def stupid_addition(num1, num2):
    if (num1, num2) == str:
      result = int(num1 + num2)
    else:
      result = str(num1 + num2) 
    return result
stupid_addition(num1, num2)
```

Comment: You may print the result returnedn by the function `print(stupid_addition(num1, num2))`

Comment: @azro it could be the indentation (along with the missing print) that caused his/her problem. I have reverted the edit for now.

Comment: @ailiya Did you properly indented your code or did you write it as above?

Comment: @AndrewL64 I indented it. But just for confirmation could you type the correct way.

Comment: @ailiya Of course.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `print` the result, using the `print` function.

```
num1 = input("Enter an integer or string: ")
num2 = input("Enter an integer or string: ")
def stupid_addition(num1, num2):
  if (num1, num2) == str:
    result = int(num1 + num2)
  else:
    result = str(num1 + num2) 
  return result

print(stupid_addition(num1, num2))
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried it and didn't get the result.